# Angular observable push to array

Tags: angular, observable

I use this code to take the names of tasks into my array barChartLabels.

```
public lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];

this.tasks.pipe(map(x => x.map(x => x.id))).toPromise().then(id => this.lineChartLabels.push(id))
```

The code is still working but there is a little problem with it. In fact it copy all names into the first index of lineChartLabels. I expect each name to be written in its own index of the array. How can i change the code to put each name in a single index?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need to convert the observable to promise. Infact, `toPromise()` is being discontinued in RxJS v8. Use `subscribe` instead.
2. Instead of [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the array into another array, you'd simply need to assign it.

```js
public barChartLabels: Label[] = [];

this.tasks.pipe(
  map(t => t.map(t => t.name))
).subscribe(
  names => this.barChartLabels = names
);
```